# Change a MAC-Adress persistently

Tags: 16.04, networking, udev

I am currently trying to change a HWaddr persistently. `ifconfig eno0 down`, `ifconfig eno0 hw ether 01:02:03:04:05:06` and `ifconfig eno1 up` works fine, but I could not find a way to make this persistent.

I found [Changing Network Interfaces name Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04), which suggests to add `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub` and run `update-grub`. This did not change anything for me.

Also, like suggested in [Configuring a network interface and changing mac adress permanently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231075/configuring-a-network-interface-and-changing-mac-adress-permanently) setting /etc/network/interfaces to

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
pre-up ifconfig eno1 hw ether 01:02:03:04:05:06
```

did not work (Hardwareadress just stays the same).

The second advide was to use udev. I tried `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}==01:02:03:04:05:06, ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}"=="1", NAME="eno1"`. While running `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=net` seems to change something (as one can see using `udevadm control`, it does not change the hardware address. After a reboot, the adress also stays the same. Does someone have an idea how to further debug this?

Comment: If you can change MAC address from command line, why not make a bash script out of your commands and run that script at boot up ?

Comment: hatterman  is right - taken from above link by George:  network device MAC addresses are hardcoded into the device. You can't ever 'permanently' change the MAC address that a device has. What /etc/network/interfaces, MAC Changer, and Network Manager (via the 'cloned MAC address' function) do is they temporarily change the Ethernet address advertised, (...), it needs to be run at boot time. /etc/network/interfaces does this at boot time, but you lose Network Manager management of devices.